# Multi-Root Tree Structure

Tags: data-structures, tree, big-o

I have a data such that there are many parents each with 0-n children where each child can have 0-n nodes.  Each node has a unique identifier (key) Ultimately, the parents are not connected to each other.  It seems like this would be a list of trees, however that seems imprecise.  I was thinking of joining them with a dummy root.

I need to be able to assembly a list of nodes that occur:

- from any given node down (children)
- from any given node down (children) then up to the root (up to the specific parent)
- the top level parent of any given node (in an O(n) operation)
- the level of the child in the tree (in an O(n) operation)

The structure will contain 300,000 nodes.

I was thinking perhaps I could implement a List of Trees and then also maintain a hash lookup structure that will reference a specific key value to provide me with a node as a starting point.

Is this a logical structure? Is there a better way to handle it?  It seems crude to me.

Comment: Is the tree relatively static or is it frequently modified (i.e. has nodes either added or deleted)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned in find a root node quickly you can think of create a tree where each node points to another tree.

Comment: That's why I like data structures, you can do crazy things with it. The limit is your imagination.